# need to get more than 50000 records in mysql query

Tags: mysql, database

I need to fetch 50000 records at a time because I can't use limit as I need to sync records from store to crm. Currently if I call 20000 records at a time, it's good but if more than 30000, it's not.

```
SELECT 
    order_num,
    o.uid AS uid,
    o.create_date AS create_date,
    shipping_name,
    shipping_company,
    shipping_address1,
    shipping_address2,
    shipping_city,
    shipping_state,
    shipping_province,
    shipping_zip,
    shipping_country
FROM
    orders o
        LEFT JOIN
    users u ON o.uid = u.uid
WHERE
    o.status = 'Completed'
```

I am running this query that results more than 50000 records. Because I am using API to sync these records to another CRM, when running the script, it's showing blank page... Also , if I am using LIMIT 0,20000 .. it's running good

Plz suggest me .. Thanks

Comment: you have any index on tables? use explain query for this.

Comment: I am only using primary key index..nothing else

Comment: Let's see if we can piece this... Try just getting the primary key for your records and forget about the join. Do you get better results now?. Next, try using indexes on your tables and run "explain", see if it gets better. If it doesn't try getting again all your id's and get the related info for each one of them: you may hit the database server 50000 times, but you're not likely to timeout. EDIT: Just primary keys?. You should index u.uid too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the language of your script, i think you're hitting a max execution time and/or memory limit directive. Check your error log for more information and - if you are using PHP - just add the following lines to the beginning of your script to avoid these problems:

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", "-1");
ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```